# AJAX - Using ajax to call mySQL data with Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

I am new to programming for Web Applications

I am making a web service app using AJAX, mySQL, Node.js and Express.

I have made a database for mySQL and have connected it.

The problem i am facing is using AJAX to call mySQL data and to display it on my web-page using Node.JS / Express.

The code i have for the server and database connection:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
//Import mySQL module
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//Connection object using credentials
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "data",
    password: "database",
    database: "mydb"
});

//Connecting to the database
con.connect(

    function(err){
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("Database Connected");
        }

    );

con.end();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

I will be creating a new js file to contain my AJAX code, however i do not know how to start constructing it. My aim is to use Node.js/Express to call information from my database into a table which i have formed using Bootstrap

Thanks

Comment: did you try to search for that in tutorial sites? like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xEmZGHIHP4

Comment: Since you don't really have a solid question, I can't really give you a solid answer. Sounds like you want to make requests to an API which will then give you a response with your data. Rather than repeating specific database queries for each collection of data you want to fetch, you can organize your data into an API. This link might help build an express API: https://www.codementor.io/wapjude/creating-a-simple-rest-api-with-expressjs-in-5min-bbtmk51mq and this is a cloud hosted api for testing sample ajax calls with that might be helpful: https://reqres.in/

Comment: The tutorial i have come across, i viewed the example code..Are the app.get followed by the function considered as AJAX?

Comment: AJAX is a client side (within the browser) request to the server which usually sends a response back with data. This happens _asynchronously_ without the page reloading. AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.  This might help you understand what AJAX is: https://www.seguetech.com/ajax-technology/

Comment: The tutorial posted above in the comment does not use a separate AJAX set of functions. Will I need to create these functions in a separate JS file or would the functions in server.js be sufficient to fulfil my aim ?